# Compartir informacion entre un servicio y mi componente angular

Tags: angular

Tengo un servicio y un componente, en mi servicio hago una llamada GET a mi API, recibo la respuesta con los datos, y quiero compartir esos datos en otro componente que tengo y desde el cual no he realizado la llamada.

Hago una llamada a mi servicio llamado auth.service.ts desde mi componente llamado login.component.ts

Y quiero que los datos se muestren en home.component.ts

Mi servicio:

```
    get empresa() {
        return{ ...this._empresa }
      }
    
      constructor(public Http: HttpClient) {}
    
// El console.log que tengo en el tap, me devuelve los datos
    
      getEmpresa(id) {
        return this.Http.get(this.url + '/get-empresa/' + id)
          .pipe(
            //map( empresa => this._empresa = empresa),
            tap( empresa => console.log(empresa) ),
            tap( empresa => this._empresa = empresa),
          );
      }
```

Mi home.component.ts (

```
get empresa() {
  return this.authService.empresa;
}

console.log(this.empresa);
```

Esto es lo que recibo ->
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi login.component.ts que es desde donde hago la petición si que recibo los datos

```
this.authService.getEmpresa(this.usuario.id).subscribe(
            response => {
              if(response['code'] == 200) {
                this.empresas = response;
                console.log('RESPUESTA');
                console.log(this.empresas);
              }
            },
            error => {
              console.log(<any>error);
            }
          );
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya que lo quieres es compartir datos puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

Crea un servicio `EmpresaService` que sea el que se encargue de guardar los datos de las empresas. Este servicio contendrá un observable que será expuesto a los clientes para que puedan recibir los nuevos datos en el momento que lleguen, de esta forma los datos estarán centralizados:

```
export class EmpresaService {
  private empresas$ = new BehaviorSubject<Empresa[]>([]);

  setEmpresas(empresas: Empresa[]) {
    this.empresas$.next(empresas);
  }
  getEmpresas() {
    return this.empresas$.asObservable();
  }

  constructor() {}
}
```

Luego, de donde sea que recuperes los datos de las empresas, debes pasarlos a `EmpresaService` usando la función `setEmpresas`. Esa función se encargará de emitir un evento para que todos los clientes reciban los nuevos datos.

Servicio de ejemplo que simula una carga de datos asíncrona:

```
export class LoginService {
  constructor(private empresaService: EmpresaService) {
    // simulación de proceso asíncrono para obtener los datos
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.empresaService.setEmpresas([
        {
          nombre: 'Empresa 1'
        },
        {
          nombre: 'Empresa 2'
        }
      ]);
    }, 5000);
  }
}
```

Por último, inyectas el servicio en el componente dónde quieres recibir los datos y te suscribes al observable usando la función `getEmpresas`:

```
export class AppComponent {
  empresas : Empresa[]
  constructor(
    private empresaService: EmpresaService,
    private loginService: LoginService) {} 
  
  ngOnInit(){
    this.empresaService.getEmpresas().subscribe(empresas => this.empresas = empresas)
  }
}
```

De esa forma te queda un flujo de datos ordenado y centralizado en el cual solo hay que suscribirse al servicio `EmpresaService` para recibir los datos.

Agrego una [demo en vivo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-amcx9x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) para que puedas revisarla.